# "permission denied error" but script works perfectly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, nmap

I was watching the infamous beginners' network pentesting video of Heath Adams and was attempting to make nmap staging script.

Can someone explain why I am getting this irksome **permission denied** error where I defined the **ports** variable even though my script has been running without a hitch up until this point?

Here is the staging script I am attempting:

````bash
#!/bin/bash

#creating a temp directory to store the output of initial scan
mkdir tempStager

#scannig with given flags and storing the results
echo beginning nmap scan
nmap $*  > tempStager/scan.txt
echo basic nmap scan complete

#retrieving open ports
cat tempStager/scan.txt |grep tcp |cut -d " " -f 1| tr -d "/tcp" > tempStager/ports.txt
sleep 2
ports=cat tempStager/ports.txt| awk '{printf "%s,",$0}' tempStager/ports.txt
ip=echo $* | awk 'NF{ print $NF }'

#scanning with -A
#echo ""
#echo starting nmap scan with -A
#nmap -A -p$ports $ip


#removing temp directory
#rm -r tempStager```
````

Comment: Paste it into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for some immediate fixes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ports=cat tempStager/ports.txt| awk '{printf "%s,",$0}' tempStager/ports.txt
```

assigns the variable the value `"cat"` and then tries to execute `tempStager/ports.txt` as an executable. But the file is not an executable (it doesn't have the `x` bit set, so it cannot be executed.

`ports` only exists for the runtime of the (would-be) program, it is not available after the program has terminated (which the program does immediately, because your shell fails to run it).

You are also specifying stdin *and* a file to awk.

If you want to assign the output of awk to a variable, you must use command substitution:

```
ports="$(awk '{printf "%s,",$0}' tempStager/ports.txt)"
```